# Get Html form when click button

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to take html form when clicci button inside. 
Just as happens on jquery Validate

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
                console.log(form);                   
                saveFunction(form);
            },
```

the log of this form is the structure of the form where I clicked

Inside to saveFunction form is

```
[object HTMLFormElement]
```

the structure of my page has many forms that you create a loop where inside there is a button like this

```
<button type="button" onclick="delete()">Delete</button>
```

and I want to take the structure of the form where I clicked this button, with something like find or closest

Comment: Try `.html()` method.

Comment: `$(this).closest('form').html();` is this you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="delete(elimina_foto($(this)))">Delete</button>
```

js:

```
function elimina_foto(n) {
    var form = n.closest('form');
    console.log(n);
    console.log(form.attr('action'));
    console.log(form.serialize());
}
```